# Can search return sites based on the value in a list in those sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search, managed-property

How would I return a set of websites based on an entry in a list for each of those sites?

Essentially I have 10 Project sets and each of those sites as a list called ReviewTracking. In that list I have two columns (Reviewer and Status) and an entry with my name and status set to yes or no for each of the 10 project sites.

In search, I would like to retrieve all projects sites that I've marked as reviewed. Is it possible to return sites based on entries in a list within those sites?

Comment: Are you building a content search web part? If so you may build a content type "ReviewTracking". In the web part search for item with status = yes.

Comment: Not exactly CSWP, I'm trying to configure the Search Results WebPart for this. Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to refine between projects he's reviewed or not reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your search results to return the list items themselves, and use a search result template to display the site the list item is in instead of the list item itself.

Comment: That's an interesting way to think about it. Hadn't considered that as an option. I'm having trouble coming up with the search query (kml) for this however. I tried `contentclass:sts_web propReviewer={User.name} propReview="Yes"` but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Drop the contentclass; propreviewer is a property of your list item, not the web. That will return your list items. Then you just want to display their web URL in your display template (as well as any other relevant metadata).